# How to disable screen capture/screenshot in react native app

Tags: android, react-native

I have came across few solutions specific for Android to prevent screen-capturing and taking screenshots. But how do i disable screen-capturing in react native in specific page/module?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to create a bridge and call java code to do that. Or, simply include [this library](https://github.com/kristiansorens/react-native-flag-secure-android).